# ios 8 UIIMagePickerController showing a black preview screen alternate times in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app on click of a UIButton am opening camera.Once the camera is opened a black preview is shown instead of the capturing image,but Retake and Use photos buttons are visible.This back preview is shown for camera in iPhone6 but works fine in iPhone 5, 5s.In my app once the user clicks use photo button,am navigating to other UIViewController.The captured image, which is stored in variable and will be passed to another UIViewController.From this UIViewController it will be posted to server.What is causing the black preview screen am not able to figure out.Looking for help.Below is my code:

```
ON button click
{

[self takeNewPhotoFromCamera];

}

- (void)takeNewPhotoFromCamera
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
    controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    controller.allowsEditing = NO;
    //controller.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self callOperationQue];

    }

 }


- (void)callOperationQue{
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=8.0)
{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{


        [self.navigationController presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
    }];

}
else
{

    [self.navigationController presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
}

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];

UIImage *image1 = [info valueForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
// imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);


UIImage *newImage = [self squareImageWithImage:image1 scaledToSize:sz];
imgVwProfile.image=newImage;
CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f;
int maxFileSize = 250*1024;

imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, compression);

while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
{
    compression -= 0.1;
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, compression);
}

//passing image data to other UIViewController
CreateClaimViewController *address=[[CreateClaimViewController alloc]init];
address.img=newImage;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:address animated:NO];

}
//resizing of image
- (UIImage *)squareImageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
double ratio;
double delta;
CGPoint offset;

//make a new square size, that is the resized imaged width
CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(newSize.width, newSize.width);

//figure out if the picture is landscape or portrait, then
//calculate scale factor and offset
if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {
    ratio = newSize.width / image.size.width;
    delta = (ratio*image.size.width - ratio*image.size.height);
    offset = CGPointMake(delta/2, 0);
} else {
    ratio = newSize.width / image.size.height;
    delta = (ratio*image.size.height - ratio*image.size.width);
    offset = CGPointMake(0, delta/2);
}

//make the final clipping rect based on the calculated values
CGRect clipRect = CGRectMake(-offset.x, -offset.y,
                             (ratio * image.size.width) + delta,
                             (ratio * image.size.height) + delta);


//start a new context, with scale factor 0.0 so retina displays get
//high quality image
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sz, YES, 0.0);
} else
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sz);
}
UIRectClip(clipRect);
[image drawInRect:clipRect];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Check whether there is any memory leak in your project. It may cause blank camera screen.

Comment: if there is a memory leak,how it works normally in iPhone 5

Comment: I have the same issue on 2 different apps. I'm wondering if its an iOS8 bug, but it seems for me too huge to have not been noticed buy Apple guys. Maybe because i'm still compiling with Xcode5?

Comment: am using Xcode 6 but still i have the issue

Comment: Same issue with my iPhone6 iOS8.1

Comment: is it working fine in iphone 5 ios 8?

Comment: yes its working fine in every device except for iPhone 6.In iPhone 6 am getting black preview alternate times i.e. 1st it works, 2nd time it does not 3rd time it work

Comment: I was having the same issue on an iPad 2, but not an iPad 3. I just tried restoring the iPad 2 and it solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

try to check app's permissions in phone settings first. I have experienced such issue with black screen and the camera deny permission was on. I did not understand how it happened, because I assumed that I allowed camera.

Also you'd better to check permission before presenting controller

```
 AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) { // authorized
        [self takeFoto];
    }
    else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied){ // denied
        [self showCameraDeniedError];
    }
    else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted){ // restricted
        [self showCameraDeniedError];
    }
    else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){ // not determined

        [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
            if(granted){ // Access has been granted ..do something
                [self takeFoto];
            } else {
                [self showCameraDeniedError];
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: I am using UIImagePickerController,does AVAuthorizationSatus work with this

Comment: @user2552751 yep, it does. I use it also for taking fotos. However, it works from iOS7 or later. You can omit permission check in earlier versions, if you support them, because it is not avaliable there.

Comment: I have this problem only in iOS10 and only in landscape mode.. Any views?

Answer (score 0):

this is an old but good answer, I also faced the black camera preview issue, on iOS7 mostly.  You can fix your issue.  First you need to comment out your code which executes after a picture is captured.  Now that the camera just opens, takes a pic, and you dismiss it without processing the image, you will notice the UIImagePickerController works just fine or not.  Now uncomment the image processing code out, you will get a black preview after a few pics are taken and processed most likely.  If this works, start adding back some of the image processing code, else look at how your presenting the UIImagePickerController, you don't need to call addOperationWithBlock, since the button click already is on the main thread.  Get rid of that call, do it normally.  Make sure your not doing anything funny with async calls after the pic is taken.  In my case I had multiple threads executing after a pic was taken, which caused the next presentViewController attempt to fail with black preview.  After I fixed it so that the async action was a single thread doing background image processing, it worked all the time properly.